# How to get a key value in a json object and affect it into the same object?

Tags: json, object, variables

I have  a json object with some keys and values.
I would like to get a generic way to get one of these values and set (into the same object) a variable with this value.

```
myObj = {
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "cars": {
    "key":"John",
    "car2":"BMW",
    "car3":"Fiat"
  }
 }

myObj = {
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "cars": {
    "other-name":"John",
    "car2":"BMW",
    "car3":"Fiat"
  }
 }
```

Comment: what's language code that you using?

Comment: Js but i would like to know when im writting inside jsonfile with vi or text editor in fact no in the . js

Answer (score 0):

You can use either object.property.anotherProperty form, or object["property"]["anotherProperty"] access form to read and to set value, for example:

```
myObj.cars.car2 = myObj.cars.car3;
```

P.S. assuming Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can assign new value as follow.

myObj.cars.newKey = "Any Value"

Answer (score 0):

That's some nice answer but I would like to know when im writting inside the jsonfile on vi